# Failed to install The App, when Running My React Native Project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I have already create a React Native App and install all the Dependencies and Tolls, also Android Studio Emulator, but when I execute the commands `npm start` and its show me the option, then I chose the an a option for running in android, but after that its just running and show the emulator, but in the last it show me that its failed to install the app.

The error Show Bellow
[Error While Running my react native app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhaLb.png)
[Emulator, showing nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxm86.png)

Please help!

I have trying some solutions by searching some solutions on google, but its doesnt work yet.

After running the react-native doctor sugested by technophyle
[Results of runing react-native doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujAeC.png)

As shown in the image I have already installed the SDK tools and SDK Platforms

[All SDK tools and plkatforms installed on my Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXzM8.png)

After diagnosing with `react-native doctor` it's give the options to fix the issues by pressing *a* on keyboard.
And its automatically downloading, installing and also set up all environment system. as showing in the image below, and at the end its suggest me to restart my pc to make the changes, I have restart several times, and some times I shutdown the pc, but when I re run the project, the problem is continuing existing, and when I re run the `react-native doctor` again, its show me that the SDK is not installed.

[SDK Installation successfully and the suggestion for restarting PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Gtg.png)

[SDK Installation successfully and the suggestion for restarting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etzr9.png)

Comment: Did you try running `react-native doctor`?

Comment: technophyle
 Yes, and the result shows as in my editing post

Comment: As you can see after running the command, you need to install JDK and Android SDK.

Comment: JDK already installed and it has solved.
but the  SDK is still missing, even though I have Installed it, and setting up all environment variables.
@technophyle

Comment: @technophyle Can you take a look at the screenshoot in my updated post?

Comment: You need to set the SDK home directory somewhere. I forgot where but there should be a way. Try googling.

Comment: @technophyle can you read my last updated on my post?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your environment isn´t configured correctly, you can take a look on this https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=windows

or on this tutorial on youtube:
https://youtu.be/oorfevovPWw

I hope this may help.

Comment: By your name, I think you are a Brazilian, aren't you?
So I have seen the  first link you suggested, and this is exactly the link were I use to start my project, I follow all the things in that link, and I dont know why or where the error coming.
For the second link suggestion I have watched the video, and there he show how to start the project and all going well, but not solved my issues.
I am a beginner in react native, hope you help me.

Comment: Hi, yes I am Brazilian, this is my mail: rodrigodiasf@gmail.com, send me a message so we can discuss a possible solution. Thanks

Comment: Beleza, Rodrigo